# Flutter App Crashed in Android 5.1.1 Memu Play Emulator (Lolipop)

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, forceclose

I Uploaded a simple App to Play store, and testing it in Memu Play Emulator that has the 5.1.1 Android Lolipop Version

but, the error look like this.

[force closed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YW4A9.jpg)

when you open the app, it will look like a blank page, it should be not like that.

this is my `android/app/build.gradle`

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
    keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
}

android {
    namespace "com.extcode.project.fortify_pass"
    compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.extcode.project.fortify_pass"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration.
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
            storeFile file(keystoreProperties['storeFile'])
            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0'
    implementation("androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1")
}
```

this is my flutter version

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.10.0, on macOS 13.1 22C65 darwin-x64, locale en-ID)
    • Flutter version 3.10.0 on channel stable at /Users/adithyafirmansyahputra/fvm/versions/3.10.0
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 84a1e904f4 (6 weeks ago), 2023-05-09 07:41:44 -0700
    • Engine revision d44b5a94c9
    • Dart version 3.0.0
    • DevTools version 2.23.1

[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.0)
    • Android SDK at /Users/adithyafirmansyahputra/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-33, build-tools 33.0.0
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.12+0-b1504.28-7817840)
    ✗ Android license status unknown.
      Run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` to accept the SDK licenses.
      See https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos#android-setup for more details.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.1)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Build 14B47b
    • CocoaPods version 1.12.0

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.2)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.12+0-b1504.28-7817840)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.79.2)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.66.0

[✓] Connected device (2 available)
    • macOS (desktop) • macos  • darwin-x64     • macOS 13.1 22C65 darwin-x64
    • Chrome (web)    • chrome • web-javascript • Google Chrome 114.0.5735.133

[✓] Network resources
    • All expected network resources are available.

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

I expected the app would perfectly works